# Optimization for pure vs. const function

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, pure-function

The source code I use in this post, is also available here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dGvxnv

Given this C source code:

```
int pure_f(int a, int b) __attribute__((pure));

int const_f(int a, int b) __attribute__((const));

int my_f(int a, int b) {
    int x = pure_f(a, b);
    if (a > 0) {
        return x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

If this is compiled with gcc with `-O3`, I would expect that the evaluation of `pure_f(a, b)` is moved into the `if`. But it is not done:

```
my_f(int, int):
        push    r12
        mov     r12d, edi
        call    pure_f(int, int)
        test    r12d, r12d
        cmovg   r12d, eax
        mov     eax, r12d
        pop     r12
        ret
```

On the other side, if `const_f` is called instead of `pure_f`, it is moved into the `if`:

```
my_f(int, int):
        test    edi, edi
        jg      .L4
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
.L4:
        jmp     const_f(int, int)
```

Why isn't this optimization applied for a pure function? From my understanding, this should also be possible and it seems to be beneficial.

-- EDIT --

GCC bug report (see comments): https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97307

Comment: It's a gcc bug.

Comment: Please report this to gcc's bugzilla. The sink pass has code to avoid moving a pure function across a store, but the way that code is currently written doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The difference is in `tree-ssa-sink.c` but this pass seems to treat pure/const equally...

Comment: @yugr see `gimple_vuse (stmt)` which is different for pure vs const.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is a bug in gcc:)!

Comment: Could you post a link to your bug report?

Comment: Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97307